# If $0<a<b$ then $\frac{b-a}{2(a+b)}<\frac{1}{2}$?

Tags: real-analysis

I don't know how I can prove this or whether it is right or not,

but I want to make an estimate of the term $$\frac{(a_n-b_n)^2}{2(a_n+b_n)}.$$

I have so far only figured out that it is equal to $$\frac{(b_n-a_n)^2}{2(a_n+b_n)}.$$

Answer (score 5):

- ***Proof 1*** :

Obviously : $b-a<a+b$. As $a+b>0$ we can divide each member by $a+b$.

We get : $\frac{b-a}{a+b}<1$. We conclude by dividing each member by $2$ to get : $\frac{b-a}{2\left(a+b\right)}<\frac{1}{2}$, the desired inequality.
$\square$

- ***Proof 2*** :

Note that :
$$\frac{b-a}{2\left(a+b\right)}=\frac{a+b-2a}{2\left(a+b\right)}=\frac{1}{2}-\frac{a}{a+b}$$
And the inequality holds iff $\frac{a}{a+b}>0$ (i.e. $a$ and $a+b$ are of the same sign).
$\square$

---

We can express $\frac{\left(a_n-b_n\right)^2}{2\left(a_n+b_n\right)}$ in another form :

$$\frac{\left(a_n-b_n\right)^2}{2\left(a_n+b_n\right)}=\frac{\left(a_n+b_n\right)^2-4a_nb_n}{2\left(a_n+b_n\right)}=\frac{a_n+b_n}{2}-2\frac{a_nb_n}{a_n+b_n}$$

Answer (score 1):

Yes:  $$2b-2a<2a+2b\iff 0<4a$$

which is true and you don't need $a<b$.

Answer (score 1):

Well, it is

$$\frac{b-a}{2(a+b)} < \frac{1}{2} \Leftrightarrow 2(b-a) < 2(a+b)$$

which is obviously true for $0<a<b$ and generally for any $a>0$ to be honest.

**Edit (by Hagen von Eitzen) :** $a+b >0$ is needed for the equivalence, even if weakening the case conditions down to only $a>0$.

Comment: If you suggest to weaken the conditions to $a>0$, keep in mind that $a+b>0$ is also needed for the equivalence

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Thanks for the heads up, precise !